# How to manually set output from speaker Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sinch

i have integrated sinch video calling in ios swift app. Video calling is working fine but video call sound is only coming from earpiece not from speaker how to solve this issue??

Note: my android team have manually changed output device to speaker if it is answer then how to do it please send some example.

Comment: Do you already try to override `overrideOutputAudioPort` ?
Check the official documentation on https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616443-overrideoutputaudioport

Comment: can you give some example

Answer (score 0):

s.bharti for this you use CallKit. Then your app behaves like a native app. like a WhatsApp.